# How to build charts from Elasticsearch query

Tags: elasticsearch, kibana, elasticsearch-2.0

I have a command which is able to run in Elasticsearch following something similar to https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/search-aggregations-pipeline-movavg-aggregation.html#_prediction

```
GET linux_cpu*/_search?search_type=count
{
    "aggs": {
        "my_date_histo": {
            "date_histogram": {
                "field": "@timestamp",
                "interval": "day"
            },
        "aggs": {
            "the_sum": {
                "avg": {
                    "field": "CPU(%)"
                }
            },
            "the_movavg": {
                "moving_avg": {
                    "bucketsPath": "the_sum",
                    "window": 90,
                    "model": "holt_winters",
                    "settings": {
                        "type": "add",
                        "alpha": 0.8,
                        "beta": 0.2,
                        "gamma": 0.7,
                        "period": 30
                     },
                    "predict": 30
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

However, I don't know how can I generate a graph based on the query. Could anyone help with this?

Comment: Supporting moving average is not yet possible in Kibana: https://github.com/elastic/kibana/issues/4584. But you can start looking at Timelion: http://rmoff.net/2016/03/29/experiments-with-kibana-timelion-2/

Comment: I have gone through timelion before with moving average, however, it seems that timelion can't make use of moving average to do future prediction which ES is supposed to support as stated in the link from my question. Therefore, I wonder if there is any packages can do that?